# How to pass Knockout property to Razor helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js, viewmodel

I have the following link in my view:

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Item", new { SeName = item.ItemSeName })">LinkText</a>
```

I'm using Knockout and trying to replace the code above with something like:

```
<a data-bind="text: LinkText, attr: {href: '@Url.RouteUrl("Item", new { SeName = ItemSeName })'}"></a>
```

ItemSeName  is the property of my KO view model.

How can i pass this property value to @Url.RouteUrl helper, to the routevalues object?

Comment: `'@Url.RouteUrl("Item")/' + ItemSeName())'` use that, that works if you have `ItemSeName()` as part of Knockout viewmodel. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: @ramiramilu , thanks, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Razor is server-side, knockout is client-side. It's not going to work how you'd like.

Comment: yep, i know it. and i'm trying to figure it out. Maybe i should pass some "dummy" to helper and then replace it with JS?